# Difference between pandas and spark in terms of 'in-memory' processing in python

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have learn about in-memory processing of spark which  is an advantage over pandas.
But I compare below pandas and spark program where they create dataframe and concact two columns.
In both cases  spark and pandas will do the processing in 'in-memory'as data should be in RAM for processing.So how spark gives an advantage in this scenario compared to pandas as both are processing in-memory? Also when we should go for spark and pandas?

spark :-

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([
        ("Red",1,"Apple",date(2021,1,1),''),
        ("Black",2,"Grape",date(2021,2,3),''),
        ("Yellow",3,"Banana",date(2022,2,4),'')
        ],schema="color string,sr_no long,fruit string,orderDate date,desc string")
df2 = df.withColumn("desc", concat(col("color"), col("fruit")))
print(df2.show())
```

pandas :-

```
data = {'color': ['Red', 'Black', 'Yellow'],
        'sr_no': ['1', '2', '3'],
        'fruit':['Apple','Grape','Banana'],
        'orderDate':['2021-01-01','2021-02-03','2022-02-04']
        }   
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df['desc']=df['color']+df['fruit']
print(df)
```

o/p:-

```
color,sr_no,fruit,orderDate,desc
Red,1,Apple,2021-01-01,RedApple
Black,2,Grape,2021-02-03,BlackGrape
Yellow,3,Banana|2022-02-04,YellowBanana
```

Comment: My understanding is that you will choose spark if you are interested in horizontal scaling of your use case. Spark is designed with distributed computing in mind and the scale of in-memory processing will be bigger compared to Pandas. I am not sure  if pandas has distributed computing version

Comment: Infact spark has support for Pandas using pyspark https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.html 
So basically you can use pandas in spark

Comment: If you create a DataFrame (Spark or Pandas) in memory, there is no difference (for a single machine). However, Spark is lazy : as long as you don't need the result (like read content of file for example), Spark does nothing unlike Pandas.

Answer (score 2):

(Py)Spark is designed for *big* datasets, i.e., starting at **multiple Gigabytes up to Petabytes**. Pandas natively can handle data that fits into your local memory at the time of writing, usually a **few Gigabytes**.

The costs in PySpark are complexity and money: you need a cluster of machines that needs to be managed. This is why it's often a good idea to stick to Pandas until you need more parallelization or process more data in a timeframe than can be handled through chunking locally.

Note that PySpark is not a drop-in replacement for pandas, there are some syntactical differences, but the code will look similar.

There's also the [Dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/) library for Python that allows you to have distributed computing using a mostly pandas-compatible syntax.